# how to make JAVA FX smooth scroll

Tags: javafx, smooth-scrolling

I made a costume list using a scroll pane, vbox and hboxes. i have enabled drag scroll using setPannable(true) i was wondering that there is an easy way to implement smooth scroll like in mobile apps and using drag velocity change the scrolling speed.

here is what i have done so far:

```
   ScrollPane itemGrid = new ScrollPane();
    itemGrid.setPannable(true);

    VBox gp = new VBox(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
             HBox rowBox = new HBox();
             rowBox.getChildren().add(i);

             gp.getChildren().add(rowBox);

      }


    itemGrid.setContent(gp);
```

this way i can scroll using mous drag. but it is not nice. any suggestions?